# Connecting react-draft-wyswig to redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, draftjs

I'm trying to add to redux-form field of type Editor from react-draft-wyswig. As I read from redux-form docs I need to connect it by **value** and **onChange** properties in **Field** component (from redux-form).

I built a component with additional property **value** which stores a html code of current wyswig-editor:

```
class WYSWIGField extends Component {

constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(), value: '' };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

onChange(editorState){
    this.setState({ editorState: editorState,
                          value: draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))});
    //console.log(this.state.value);
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Editor
                editorState={this.state.editorState}
                onEditorStateChange={this.onChange}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

My form:

```
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.addPost)}>
      <Field name="editor" component={WYSWIGField}/>
      <button type="submit">Add post</button>
  </form>
```

Export:

```
export default connect(null, { addPost })(
               reduxForm({form: "AddPostForm"})(Posts));
```

And action creatow where I always receive empty object without my values from editor:

```
 export function addPost(prop) {

console.log("prop", prop);

return{
    type: ADD_POST,
    payload: prop
};
}
```

Could somebody help me with this? Where I did mistake?

Thank you